# HttpEntity and responce to a try catch

Tags: http, exception, get, try-catch, spring-framework-beans

i am learning how to manage some http request with Spring Framework and create same ape to read/write on a Database.

So far i have this methods:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
  @Override
  public Book getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    logger.debug("get book with id: " + id);
    try {
      return bookService.getById(id);
    } catch (BookNotPresentException e) {
      logger.debug("book not present" + e);
      // TODO ritornare un http entity
      // -> meglio fare handler dedicato!
      return new Book(-1, "Book not Present", null, null, 0, 0, null, 0);
    }
  }
```

my big problem is how to manage the catch phase.
What i have to do? the idea is return somehow a string with "book not present".

Can you suggest something ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution here: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
and use the 5th solution proposed.